# Google Sign returns 'invalid credentials' with YouTube

Tags: swift, youtube-api, google-signin, youtube-data-api

## Introduction

I'm trying to allow my users to sign into their YouTube account via Google Sign-in. I have followed this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating), completely. It seems as if it is working. But, it's not.

---

## Set Up

I am wanting my users to be able to like a YouTube video by pressing a button. To do this, I need permission to manage their YouTube account. So, I add the scope required which I found in the [Rate Video documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/rate) provided by Google. I add it in the AppDelegate like so:

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl"]
```

Then, I click on the `GIDSignInButton` that I added to my view controller, the Google Sign-In page comes up. It asks for permission to access my Google account and manage my YouTube account. Perfect.

[image: Screenshot of the Google Sign-In page]

I allow it to manage my YouTube channel and it completes.

---

## Confirmation

I have a `UIViewController` that gets information about the signed in user's YouTube channel. Such as profile image, name, etc. So, I go on that `UIViewController` to make sure I'm actually signed in and my app knows who I am. It does. It shows the signed in user's profile image, name, etc.

---

## The Problem

So everything is working out pretty well. Now, I want to let my user rate a video by pressing a button. Here is the button's function:

```
@IBAction func likeButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    Alamofire.request("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos/rate", method: .post, parameters: ["id":"9T56NNzHE7A","rating":"like","key":API_KEY], encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response) in
        print("Like Response - \(response)")

    }
}
```

This is where I get my error. Whenever a user clicks on the button, I get this response (it's printed in the code above):

```
Like Response - SUCCESS: {
    error =     {
        code = 401;
        errors =         (
                        {
                domain = global;
                location = Authorization;
                locationType = header;
                message = "Login Required";
                reason = required;
            }
        );
        message = "Login Required";
    };
}
```

I do not understand why this is happening. I've logged in with the correct scope added.

---

## Full Code

I have followed this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating), completely.

**App Delegate**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = "xxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
    
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl"]
    
    return true
}

@available(iOS 9.0, *)
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    
    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url, sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String, annotation: [:])
    
    
}

@available(iOS, introduced: 8.0, deprecated: 9.0)
func application(application: UIApplication,openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url as URL!, sourceApplication: sourceApplication!, annotation: annotation)
}
```

**SignInViewController**

```
    @IBOutlet var signInButton: GIDSignInButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
        
        signInButton.style = .wide
  }
```

---

## Update

Thanks to a helpful answer by Aaron Halvorsen, I've learned that I need to replace my API Key with the Google Sign-In access token. Like so...

```
Alamofire.request("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos/rate", method: .post, parameters: ["access_token":userToken, "id":"9T56NNzHE7A","rating":"like"], encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response) in
            print("Like Response - \(response)")

        }
```

But, now I am getting another error. Here it is:

```
Like Response - SUCCESS: {
    error =     {
        code = 401;
        errors =         (
                        {
                domain = global;
                location = Authorization;
                locationType = header;
                message = "Invalid Credentials";
                reason = authError;
            }
        );
        message = "Invalid Credentials";
    };
}
```

I've checked the accessToken. It's is token, and it's not printing Optional. Have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is your entire answer but when you sign in you'll get a oauthtoken back which is your authorization and not an api key. Try sending your oauthtoken back with your request, I believe the key is access_token: `["access_token": OAUTH_TOKEN]`.

Comment: @Halvosren Thank you for answering! That was very helpful, but now I am getting another error. Like Response - SUCCESS: {
    error =     {
        code = 401;
        errors =         (
                        {
                domain = global;
                location = Authorization;
                locationType = header;
                message = "Invalid Credentials";
                reason = authError;
            }
        );
        message = "Invalid Credentials";
    };
}

Comment: Google api documentation says that when receiving this error: "The access token you're using is either expired or invalid." https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/handle-errors. in your case it's my guess it's not expired but just invalid, your token is a string that looks something like this: "MTQ0NjJkZmQ5OTM2NDE1ZTZjNGZmZjI3". I'm not sure beyond that what it could be. you could try some other api calls that are different scope permissions like a readonly and try that, might help you debug. trying something different but similar sometimes helps me debug. cheers.

Comment: The token looks something like this (this isn't actually it)  ve35.LmaIBHsK3dUPNR34rb0fgThwiZj-dNB7k935EhyVK1X8nkgMBmA-_3Hxhys7uk-HEm3ggg-HIgJv83RHXhGNKdVkWn0sEn7XtaWhTbeVjg8hsBK3hK8H1Gx8KzhhaEJGVg

Comment: Yeah. The access token goes into headers, not the parameters. Check out this other question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50567322/google-api-invalid-credentials?noredirect=1#comment88148712_50567322]

Comment: awesome. glad you figured it out!